# Software for interactively drawing on a torus

Tags: math-software, programming, art

This is possibly not the best place to put this, but I am looking for a software where you can draw on a plane diagram of a torus (unit square with identifications) and it automatically maps the drawing onto a 3D model of a torus. I know it is possible to do such a thing manually (c.f. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111257/how-to-manually-draw-graphs-on-a-torus)) but I would like it to be more interactive. I'm not sure if such a thing exists. If it does not, and anyone would want to work on such a thing, I'd be happy to collaborate.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any such software, but putting something together in HTML/JavaScript looks straightforward. <> Because the question may be considered off-topic for Math.SE, there's a chance it will get moved or closed. If that happens, maybe start a chat thread and ping people who comment here...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang It is simple to me conceptually, but I'm not great at graphics programming - I just never know how to start. If you want to work together on it I would be glad to help, or at least do the mathy part on my own.

Comment: There's a version displaying two canvases side-by-side; the left canvas is a $2\times2$ square-tiled piece of plane in which polygon paths in selectable colors can be drawn by mouse-clicking; the right displays (crudely, e.g., without proper spatial layering) the image under a conformal parametrization of a torus. The spatial viewpoint can be rotated using the arrow keys. I'm not yet ready to post a URL (because doing so will cause the page to get indexed by search engines), but am happy to email the URL on request.

Comment: Sure, you can email to my throwaway account (lower case L) lmroid72@gmail.com [since I'm unsure of any direct message functionality here]
@AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: For posterity (but avoiding a link-only answer), here's a reasonably-permanent URL: https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/software/Torus/index.html

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but this one draws directly on the torus: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570836/1257